# how to update formula of calculated column using PnP in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula, pnp-powershell

I want to update formula of calculated column using PnP or powershell. please note that i am using SharePoint Online.
i tried below but its giving me error. please help.

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Set-PnPField -List "CalculateDays" -Identity "MyFormula" -Values @{Formula="=222"}
WARNING: No property 'Formula' found on this field. Value will be ignored.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can update the SchemaXml property to achieve it.

```
Connect-PnPOnline –Url https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/lz –Credentials (Get-Credential)

$listName="CalculateDays"
$fieldName="MyFormula"
$formula="=222"

$field = Get-PnPField -List $listName -Identity $fieldName
[xml]$schemaXml=$field.SchemaXml
$schemaXml.Field.Formula=$formula
Set-PnPField -List $listName -Identity $fieldName -Values @{SchemaXml=$schemaXml.OuterXml}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

`Set-PnPField` uses `Field` type i.e `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Field` to internally set the property values.

This does not expose the `Formula` property of Calculated field which is of type `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldCalculated`.

So, you need to use a bit of CSOM jugglery to cast it to Calculated Field type and to get it working with PnP PowerShell as in the below mentioned code sample:

```
$context = Get-PnPContext
$field = Get-PnPField -List "CalculateDays" -Identity "MyFormula"
$calcField = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext].GetMethod("CastTo").MakeGenericMethod([Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldCalculated]).Invoke($context, $field)
$calcField.Formula = <your formula>
$calcField.Update()
$context.Load($calcField);
Invoke-PnPQuery
```

Comment: its giving me below error on $calcField = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext].GetMethod("CastTo").MakeGenericMethod([Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldCalculated]).Invoke($context, $field)

Comment: Exception calling "Invoke" with "2" argument(s): "Object does not match target type."
At line:1 char:1
+ $calcField = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext].GetMethod("C ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TargetException

Comment: works at my end ! Can you check if you are using the correct list and field internal names ?

Comment: everything is correct but i am still getting an error. do i have to install any library/sdk before i run this powershell. all my other PnP commands are working fine

Comment: I would suggest that you install [SPO CSOM SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=42038) and also ensure that you are using PowerShell v3.0 or above